# Doesn't Swift care capitalization of font name?

Tags: swift, xcode, fonts, uifont

I wrote code that can simply return UIFont which can used like this

`myLabel.font = UIFont.AppleSDGothicNeo.medium.of(20)`

And actual implementation is like this

```
extension UIFont {
    enum AppleSDGothicNeo: CustomFont {
        var familyName: String {
            return "AppleSDGothicNeo-"
        }
        
        case thin
        case light
        case regular
        case bold
        case semiBold
        case ultraLight
        case medium
    }
}

protocol CustomFont {
    var familyName : String { get }
    func of(_ size: CGFloat) -> UIFont
}

extension CustomFont {
    func of(_ size: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
        let name = familyName+String(describing: self)
        guard let font = UIFont(name: name, size: size) else {
            fatalError("Could not find Custom Font \(self)")
        }
        return font
    }
}
```

As you can see, I get font name by using `String(describing: self)` . And in case of `medium`, it will return  "AppleSDGothicNeo-medium" with its `familyName`.

But when I print out actual font name, it represents "AppleSDGothicNeo-Medium". Although `M` is a capital letter, it works fine with "AppleSDGothicNeo-medium".

So.. doesn't Swift care capitalization of font name?

Comment: Even if it resolves case-insensitively, nothing says that it's officially supported. So relying on this behavior may not be the best option. Also look at `UIFontDescriptor` instead of inventing your own way to resolve different of font, it already has all the styles, and the way to resolve font family. E.g. `UIFontDescriptor().withFamily("Apple SD Gothic Neo").withSymbolicTraits(.traitBold)` gives you a bold font for family `"Apple SD Gothic Neo"` etc

Comment: @KirilS. Thank you for your suggestion. But actually I will use that function to use my custom font. Would `UIFontDescriptor` and `SymbolicTrait` also valid for using my own font?

Comment: Yes. As long as it's added to a project.

Comment: @KirilS. I made my own descriptor like this. `let descriptor = UIFontDescriptor().withFamily("MyCustomSansTTF").withSymbolicTraits(.traitBold)` But it returns `nil` (Actually, the font name I want is "MyCustomSansTTFBold") Is it need to any further work to get the right result?